# Click a download link with Python and Selenium's Firefox Webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to consistently download historical stock data from a link which appears on the page after you hover the cursor over it. At present I have the following code which doesn't appear to find the css_selector, nor download the .csv file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

## Import Libraries
import os, sys
import time

from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.firefox.options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

## Declare Variables
ticker = 'CAT'
period1 = '1262332800'
period2 = '1537945200'
download_path = os.getcwd()
css_selector = "a.Fl\(end\):nth-child(1)"

## Configure Firefox Options
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2) # 0 means to download to the desktop, 1 means to download to the default "Downloads" directory, 2 means to use the directory 
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_path)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip/text/csv")

## Firefox driver loads historical data page
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/history?period1={}&period2={}&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
           .format(ticker, period1, period2))

## Click on 'Download Data' Link
try:
    input_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector).click()
    print('Success!')

except:
    print('Failed!!!!!')

finally:
    driver.quit()
    print('Kill Driver!')
```

The example site is:
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CAT/history?period1=1262332800&period2=1538118000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

css_selector, "a.Fl(end):nth-child(1)", is found in this section of HTML:

```
<svg class="Va(m)! Mend(5px) Stk($c-fuji-blue-1-b)! Fill($c-fuji-blue-1-b)! Cur(p)" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 48 48" data-icon="download" style="fill: rgb(0, 129, 242); stroke: rgb(0, 129, 242); stroke-width: 0; vertical-align: bottom;"><path d="M43.002 43.002h-38c-1.106 0-2.002-.896-2.002-2v-11c0-1.105.896-2 2.002-2 1.103 0 1.998.895 1.998 2v9h34.002v-9c0-1.105.896-2 2-2s2 .895 2 2v11c0 1.103-.896 2-2 2m-19-8L11.57 23.307c-.75-.748-.75-1.965 0-2.715.75-.75 1.965-.75 2.715 0l7.717 7.716V2h4v26.308l7.717-7.716c.75-.75 1.964-.75 2.714 0s.75 1.967 0 2.715L24.002 35.002z"></path></svg><span>Download Data</span>
```

My questions are:

- Is there an easier way to click on the link? xpath? partial_link?
- Am I attempting to click on the correct css_selector?
- Do I need to hover over the text in order to click on the download data link?
- How do I find the element while the site is loading? The site never finishes downloading there are continuous calls to ad servers.

Using the method .find_element_by_link_text() results in TimeoutException:

> TimeoutException                            Traceback (most recent
>   call last)     in ()
>        21 ## Go to Homepage for historical data
>        22 driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/history?period1={}&period2={}&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
>
> ---> 23            .format(ticker, period1, period2) )
>        24
>        25 print('.get() Complete!')
>
> ~/virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py
>   in get(self, url)
>       331         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
>       332         """
>   --> 333         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
>       334
>       335     @property      ~/virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py
>   in execute(self, driver_command, params)
>       319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
>       320         if response:
>   --> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>       322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
>       323                 response.get('value', None))
>
> ~/virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py
>   in check_response(self, response)
>       240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
>       241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
>   --> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       243
>       244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):
>
> TimeoutException: Message: Timeout loading page after 300000ms

My interpretation of this is that the site does not finish loading, so the try/except/finally logic never executes.

Comment: Actually `css_selector = "a.Fl\(end\):nth-child(1)"` selector is correct. Can you share exception or current output/behavior description?

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I am attempting to run both. Presently, @dbachhav 's solution link_text has worked once, but doesn't appear to work a second or third time. The site continues to load ads, I'm wondering if this impedes the progress of the driver.

Comment: Do you mean that same page behaves differently when you're trying to access it? Or you need to handle many pages and search by link text is not applicable to all of them?

Comment: Note that you're getting `TimeoutException` not because of using `find_by_link_text()`, but because of using `driver.set_page_load_timeout(3)`. It means that you should get `TimeoutException` in case page not loaded within 3 seconds. Do you really need that? Comment out that line and check again

Comment: have no idea why you removed `driver.set_page_load_timeout(3)` line from exception log, but `TimeoutException: Message: Timeout loading page after 300000ms` tells it all: WebDriver failed to load page, but not failed to find element!

Comment: I think this may be what I need. The page never stops loading as it is cycling through a list of ad servers e.g. doubleclick. Is there a way to stop the driver and work with what downloaded?

Comment: @MyopicVisage Can you remove the `<blockquote>` from the error stack trace, else debugging seems difficult

Comment: @MyopicVisage , yes you can forcibly stop page loading to download file. Check my updated answer

Comment: Reading The 4-Hour Workweek will do that to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *Is there an easier way to click on the link?*

  selecting by link text should work fine:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download Data').click()
  ```
- *Am I attempting to click on the correct css_selector?*

  yes, selector seem to be correct
- *Do I need to hover over the text in order to click on the download data link?*

  no, you don't need to hover over link

*Update*

If you need to stop page loading, try below solution:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
try:
    driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/history?period1={}&period2={}&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
           .format(ticker, period1, period2))
except TimeoutException:
    driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download Data').click()
```

Page loading will be forcibly stopped if not loaded within 10 seconds

Comment: Turns out the problem was third party ads downloading. Once the site was forcibly stopped the .find_element_by_link_text() method work consistently with several tickers. Thank you SO much. I was fighting the wrong battle.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below options

```
 1. download = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='Col1-1-HistoricalDataTable-Proxy']/section/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/a")
    download.click()
 2. download = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download Data')
    download.click()
 3. download = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Download')
    download.click()
```

Comment: 1. Do not suggest XPath expressions copied from browser dev tools: they are quite unreliable and it's hard to maintain such selectors. 2. Exactly the same solution as mine. 3. What is the point of using partial link text if search by complete link text available?

Comment: @Andersson if you look close even though he copied xpath from browser it has id which is unique and saying unreliable in this case is incorrect. It was not worth to down vote.

Comment: @TimaGegewepe , It's not an ID of link, not even ID of parent, but an ancestor. Note that in case of any modifications of ancestors outerHTML selector becomes broken and it will be hard to understand what actually wrong with it

Comment: @Andersson I know what you mean, but in your solution I can say the same. Since element itself does not have unique identifier it will be always like that.

Comment: @Andersson Imagine, there will be 2 more download buttons with the same text.

Comment: @TimaGegewepe , valid case... and imagine OP need to click all of them :) Iterating through list of `driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Download Data')` seem to be OK. Do you think it's OK to copy/paste such XPath expression for each link?

Comment: @Andersson I am against it, I did not tell that you are wrong, but wanted to clarify that if element does not have unique identifier to select it, it will always be a mess when you get changes on that page. Better to talk with devs and ask them to add Id to that element.

Comment: @TimaGegewepe , If we talk about test automation on huge web-project, then requesting unique attributes for each node you need to handle - not quite convenient... And I know for sure that using XPath with 5-6 ancestors will force you to spend 0.5-1 hour each day to update selectors...

Comment: @TimaGegewepe No locator is going to be impervious to all changes. The least likely to change is by link text. They would have to add another button with the exact same text, which is probably not very likely. Using a locator with 6 levels and with 3 indices is MUCH more likely to be fragile. The two are not the same... not even close.

Comment: @Andersson Are you using page object model? You shouldn't need to spend that much time that often updating locators unless you have changes being pushed multiple times a day.

Comment: @JeffC , yep, we're using Page object. It's not a web-project, but there is also UI with DOM similar to HTML... And a lot of time wasted for locators update. We have no such tools as CSS-selectors or XPath thus not enough flexibility. However if we were using such XPath as `//*[@id='Col1-1-HistoricalDataTable-Proxy']/section/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/a` it wouldn't help much :)